# How to pass a path as a parameter into a second application in vc++?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

**Hi!**

Could someone answer my question, please?

I have an application, which is being developed in the Visual C++.
This application calls a second executable.
It passes a file path as a parameter.
How to do it correctly?
I mean double quotes, spaces and other special characters or their combinations.
For example, file My Doc.doc should be "My Doc.doc" (with double quotes).
`PathQuoteSpaces` is not a solution for me.
I need long paths (longer than MAX_PATH) and always well-formed parameter.
I call a MS's application, and their standard is important.

P. S.
I know, that there are answers for similar questions, but they do not solve my problem.

*Thank you very much*

**Continuation:**

Thank you for the answers.

I have posted the code.
It looks a bit like a pseudo-code,
because of objects and functions.
I need a well-formed parameter (Script).
The drag and drop on Windows produce such literals.

```
ShellExecute(
0,
L"open",
(GetPathQuoted(Monad::File::GetFolder(FOLDERID_System) + L"\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\PowerShell.exe")).c_str(),
(L"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File " + GetPathQuoted(Script)).c_str(),
nullptr,
0);
```

I am sorry for posting a duplicate question.
I didn't know, that " can not be in Windows file paths.

I highly appreciate helpful answers

Comment: Can you include the code where you're starting the second application?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You shouldn't post duplicates of other questions, just because the original ones don't have an answer which is suitable for you. If someone finds an answer, they should answer there, not here. On the other hand, if this question is not a duplicate, please edit it , link the similare questions and explain how yours is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the UNICODE version of PathQuoteSpaces , MAX_PATH has a value of 32,767 which should be more than enough.